# Dotnet Test Command Unknown switch, -r

Tags: .net, docker, testing, .net-core

Trying to update a docker container used for testing. I'm trying to pass the `-r` flag to set the output directory. All of my attempts have been met with:

```
test_image_1  | MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
test_image_1  | Switch: -r /app/TestResults
```

The actual command being run:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test",  "-r \"/app/TestResults\"", "-l:trx;verbosity=detailed"]
```

I've tried with the path unescaped, and I've tried with the `-r` after the `-l`. Prior to this it had been using the `-l` without issue. The docs are not very helpful in that they imply `-r some/Path/` is fine.

Per the docs:

```
-r|--results-directory <RESULTS_DIR>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets read the error carefully:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: -r /app/TestResults
```

Let's compare this to a really unknown switch:

```
$ dotnet test -X foobar
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: -X
```

See the difference? If the switch (`-X`) is unknown, it prints out the switch (`-X`). In your case it prints out `-r /app/TestResults`. It sees that as one single switch.

That argument is really supposed to be two (`-r` and `/app/TestResults`) separate arguments. So just do that in your `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test",  "-r", "/app/TestResults", "-l:trx;verbosity=detailed"]
```

Comment: Sorry, how or why would a CLI behave this way? The docs make no mention of this behavior?

Comment: The current CLI behaviour is - to me, at least - the normal one. If you are calling the command in a POSIX-like shell (`bash`, `zsh`, `git-bash`)  you run `dotnet test -r /app/TestResults`. The shell splits the input into words (splits using spaces), and passes each term as a single argument. So the command that the shell runs is `dotnet`, `test`, `-r`, `/appTestResults`, which is basically what have you provide in your `Dockerfile`.

If the dotnet CLI would take `-r /app/TestResults` as a single argument, you would have to call it as `dotnet test "-r /app/TestResults"` using the shell.

Comment: ...No I don't really think so? `git commit -m 'My message'` is the syntax that git, as an example of a CLI, uses to pass flags with arguments. `-m` is the flag, which takes an argument ('My message'). Much the same, `dotnet test -r somePath`, as per the docs, presumably should work the exact same way?

Comment: Yes, the two commands you listed work the same way. I am glad we are on the same page so far. How would you write the git command in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Oh, and if you are confused about quoting (`"` and `'`), it disables the shell's default behaviour of splitting using spaces for the quoted argument. `dotnet test -r "foo bar"` becomes `dotnet`, `test`, `-r`, `foo bar`. `git commit -m 'foo bar'` becomes `git`, `commit`, `-m`, `foo bar`